# iOS Build Succeeds, but Displaying Blank Screen Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, macos, dart

I'm working on an App which runs perfectly on the Android platform.. then I got a Mac, setup installation and all.. I tried running the iOS version of the app. It installs on the emulator, starts to load and then displays a blank screen..

Here's my log from Xcode..

```
2022-09-16 10:04:30.401305-0700 Runner[35230:248996] Metal API Validation Enabled
2022-09-16 10:04:30.516910-0700 Runner[35230:248996] GrMtlCommandBuffer: WARNING: Creating MTLCommandBuffer while in background.
2022-09-16 10:04:30.518412-0700 Runner[35230:248996] GrMtlCommandBuffer: WARNING: Creating MTLCommandBuffer while in background.
2022-09-16 10:04:30.577497-0700 Runner[35230:249203] flutter: The Dart VM service is listening on http://127.0.0.1:61436/iHZJYa2Yv5g=/
2022-09-16 10:05:06.096822-0700 Runner[35230:249183] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics
```

And here's what it displays..

[image]

Comment: I have exact same issue. Only common dependency is flutter_image_compress. I'm trying without it now. I'm also using Firebase.

Comment: did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: nahh, I haven't .. Had to restart the project again from scratch..

Answer (score 3):

I just experienced the same issue and found the fix, at least, for me:

I added the key (inside the dictionary) and its value as an empty dictionary, like this:UISceneConfigurationsUIApplicationSceneManifest

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
    <dict/>
</dict>
```

Note, if your app does not support multiple scenes (i.e. multiple windows or screens), then this is sufficient (and may avoid a strange black screen!):

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
    <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
    <dict/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other possible solution (if adding UIApplicationSceneManifest won't help) - simply upgrading xCode to the latest. In my case 14.3.1.

This cost me lots of time.